# Rails tutorial 3.2 chapter 8, cant get signout to destroy current_user in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I can't get the sign out button to function properly.  I've added a test to the _header.html.erb partial that will add a link to show whether or not current_user is nil.  After clicking the sign out link under the Account list item, it still shows that it is not nil.  And it never shows the sign in link, so it always thinks there is a user logged in.

Can somebody take a look at this?

Here is a link to my repository:

https://github.com/davissean/sample_app

Answer (score 7):

Try 
`rake db:reset`
in the terminal and then restart the rails server

I had the same problem. Spent 6+ hrs rechecking code and testing. Everything checked out, but still never got it to work locally, so I pushed it to heroku... and it worked.

But the problem persisted in chapter 9, until I auto-populated the database, hence the `db:reset`

And, don't forget to run `rake db:test:prepare` or your tests will fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the problem with my version, but I asked a friend a while back to test it on his machine and he said that it worked fine.  So I cloned the repository again and it worked.. fine.  I'm pretty sure I had tried db:reset because it says to do that in the tutorial somewhere.  I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that

https://github.com/davissean/sample_app/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb, line 25

sets a local variable to nil rather than @current_user.